# Angular 2 XSRFStrategy

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular 2 v2.3.1 (latest version).
I need to send to my backend X-CSRF-TOKEN in request header. I found a solution on angular 2 documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#http

I implement my own XSRFStrategy:

```
export class IlmsCookieStrategy implements XSRFStrategy {

constructor(
    private cookieName: string = 'CSRF-TOKEN',
    private headerName: string = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN') { }

configureRequest(req: Request): void {
    console.log('Configure request');
    let token = __platform_browser_private__.getDOM().getCookie(this.cookieName);
    if (token && !req.headers.has(this.headerName)) {
      req.headers.set(this.headerName, token);
    }
}
}
```

And I try to load this in my main.ts:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(
    AppModule,
    [
        {
            provide: XSRFStrategy,
            useClass: IlmsCookieStrategy
        }
    ]
```

);

But the console log is not showing and the header not added to my request header. What's wrong? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app.module.ts, replace useValue with useFactory.

```
providers: [
      { provide: XSRFStrategy, useFactory: () => new IlmsCookieStrategy() } ],
```

That worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't work with ahead of time compilation. @DineshRS has the better answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using Class in your main.ts, try using "useValue" & implement your own xsrfStrategy as below:

```
import { HttpModule, XSRFStrategy, CookieXSRFStrategy, Http } from '@angular/http';

export function IlmsCookieStrategy(http: Http) {
  return new CookieXSRFStrategy('RESPONSE_TOKEN', 'X-CSRFToken');
}
```

& in your app Module use it like below:

```
providers: [
    { provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: IlmsCookieStrategy}
],
```

Hope this works for you.